# using a scalar function within a LIKE on the same query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables as follows:

```
CREATE Spaces (spaceID int, spaceName nvarchar(20)) TABLE
CREATE Hurdles( hurdleID int, aptID int, floorID int) TABLE
```

In addition, I have a scalar function called fsGetAptName that takes a floorID and an aptID and returns a nvarchar(2) string.

I want to create a query that takes aptID and floorID from each row on the Hurdles function and uses the return value of the function to get a spaceID on the Spaces table using a spaceNAME in the WHERE clause with LIKE '%' + returnValueFromScalarFunction + '%'

Can this be accomplished in one query, or I need to run this in a loop within a table function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a computed column on Hurdles
   A UDF will kill performance, better to pre-generate in the table
2. Just JOIN the 2 tables. No loops needed
3. Expect rubbish performance with a leading wildcard

So, something like this

```
ALTER TABLE Hurdles
    ADD AptNameSearch = '%' + (some expression here) + '%' PERSISTED
GO


SELECT ...
FROM
    Hurdles H
    JOIN
    Spaces S ON S.spaceName LIKE H.AptName
WHERE
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @gbk, could you help me write the expression for the computed column? I tried %' + dbo.fsGetAptNumber(hurdle_apt_id) but got errors.

Comment: Got it, I just forgot that the scalar function returned an int, so I had to cast it:
 '%' + CAST( dbo.fsGetAptNumber(hurdle_apt_id) as nvarchar(2) )
Thanks a lot for your help!